# Empty form data issue at Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm tired of pulling my hair... Can someone tell me what is going on with this code?

Basicly, I'm just trying to get data from a form. I checked hundred of times my controller, model and view but no chance for making thing work. My debug @program result is always like these eventhough I fill in ALL of fields: BLANK.

```
 --- !ruby/object:Program attributes:   
id:    
title:    
content:   
active:    
created_at:    
updated_at:
```

Here are codes:

Controller:

```
   class ProgramsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @program = Program.all
  end

  def show
    @program = Program.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @program = Program.new

    if @program.save
      redirect_to 'index'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def new 
    @program = Program.new
  end


  def edit
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :active, :content, :title

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true

end
```

View:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Program Adding</title>
</head>
<body>

    <% if @program.errors.any? %>
    <% @program.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <%= msg %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <%= form_for(@program) do |p|%>
    <%= p.label :title%><br />
    <%= p.text_field :title %><br />

    <%= p.label :content%><br />
    <%= p.text_area :content %><br />

    <%= p.label :active%><br />
    <%= p.text_field :active %><br />

    <%= p.submit %>

    <% end %>

    <%= debug @program %>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that you are not passing in the form values to your create action.

```
@program = Program.new
```

Try replacing that line with

```
@program = Program.new(params[:program])
```

This is all assuming you are using the standard restful routing.

Cheers.